# Add intermediate element in template on condition

Tags: html, css, angular

I am working on a CSS that I can't modify and I need to wrap an element on a condition, and to remove the wrap if the condition isn't verified.

In other words, I want the output is this if the condition is verified:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

And, otherwise, this:

```
<my-component></my-component>
```

I can't just remove the `wrapper` class because it would break some CSS rule, and I can't use `display: contents;` since it's not compatible with IE.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried [ngClass]? https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: @VascoCC I'm sorry, but I can't just remove the class, as I said in the question

Comment: Besides the case when optional wrapping should be applied to multiple elements, this problem is also relevant if the element(s) inside the wrapper have ids which should not be repeated

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div class="wrapper" *ngIf="condition">
      <my-component></my-component>
</div>        
<my-component *ngIf="!condition"></my-component>
```

Comment: Or you can use : [ngClass]="wrapper: condition"
on the div

Comment: This is the only working solution that pop in my mind. But maybe mine was a bad example because I used a component, but in my actual code I've a lot of elements to be wrapped, and it would result in a lot of duplicated code! Not a suitable solution

Answer (score -1):

Something like this.

```
<div [ngClass]="{'wrapper': CONDITION}">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't just remove the class, as I said in the question